# How to get multiple keybinding working in both pressing orders

Tags: java, swing, combinations, key-bindings

I have this

```
Action openFileChooserAction = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed");
                openFileChooser();
            }
        };
        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('O', KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK);
        centerPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "openFileChooser");
        centerPanel.getActionMap().put("openFileChooser", openFileChooserAction);
```

If I press `ctrl` and then `o` it works, viceversa it doesnt. How can I get it working also when I press first `o` and then `ctrl`?

Comment: Very good question! I will have an answer up in a bit, but the long and short of it is "extended modifiers" and how they play a part in all this...

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper thanks, I didnt on purpouse ^^.. Anyway thanks for the quick hint, at least I have something to google in the meanwhile..

Comment: Pahahaha, about halfway done, just realized, why on earth would you want your code to react to the reversal? Isn't the opposite usually better?

Comment: Ok, just about done, now last thing, which shift should I be looking out for? Do you want to include both shifts? Or just one? I have it built on just the left shift but I can do both if you'd like?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper I come from my own implementation using KeyListener order independent. Anyway, what you mean by shift?

Comment: The shift button, there are 2 on each keyboard, would you like the program to react to both shifts? Meaning, it doesn't matter if I do the right or the left?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper ah ok, to both, if its not a problem..

Comment: done, tell me what you think!

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this. The is not the way KeyStrokes work on any platform. To do a "copy" of text you do "Ctrl+C" NOT "C+Ctrl". This is a bad design for your application and that is way it is not supported in the standard JDK.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your comment, lets say it was a merely technical questions. I will think about implementing it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, psyche! Guess you don't need extended modifiers! My bad... ;P

You could use them, but I figured the simpler the better, especially if it's faster!

```
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SOQ18 implements KeyListener
{

   public boolean o, shift;
   public JFrame f;
   public JLabel l;

   public SOQ18()
   {

      f = new JFrame();
      l = new JLabel();
      f.setSize(200,200);
      f.setLocation(200,200);
      f.add(l);
      l.setText("Testing testing, 123...");

      f.addKeyListener(this);

      f.setVisible(true);


   }

   /** Will translate and handle the keystrokes as they are pressed and released */
   private void keyTranslate(KeyEvent e, boolean b)
   {

      int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

      if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode).equals("O"))
      {

         o = b;

      }

      if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode).equals("Shift"))
      {

         shift = b;

      }

      if(o && shift)
      {

      //do whatever code you wanted to do here, but in the meantime...
         l.setText("They have both been pressed!");

      }

      else
      {
         l.setText("Not yet...");
      }

   }

   /** Handle the key typed event */
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
   {

      // do nothing

   }

   /** Handle the key pressed event */
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
   {

      keyTranslate(e, true);

   }

   /** Handle the key released event */
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
   {

      keyTranslate(e, false);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      SOQ18 soq = new SOQ18();

   }

}
```

Now, as you can see, your code hasn't been implemented yet. Forgive me for I had no idea what your code was doing and since I didn't have any of the files and stuff necessary to test it on my computer, I just gave a shell of a program above. I'm sure you can edit this to make it work in your own way!

Now, let's explain what's going on. Ignore the `JFrame` and `JLabel`, they are simply there to prove to you that all this code is actually working. I imported `KeyEvent` and `KeyCode` so that I can check which key has been pressed, as you can see in my method, `keyTranslate()`. Then, I used the built in methods from the interface `KeyListener` to call `keyTranslate()` whenever a key was pressed and released. Lastly, `keyTranslate()` will check ONLY for o and either shift button via the if statement and the booleans. If anything doesn't make sense, feel free to ask!

Comment: Yeah dont worry, it is normal, I just wrote a snippet of my code. Anyway you are also using the keyListener as I was :)